# SignalR hub not found after website is published

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I have an ASP.Net Core 3.1 WebApp which includes Razor Pages, Api controllers and a SignalR hub. My `Startup.cs` looks like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddRazorPages();
    services.AddSignalR(options =>
    {
        options.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
    });
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddSingleton<HubManager>();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        endpoints.MapControllers();
        endpoints.MapHub<MainHub>("/MainHub");
    });
}
```

In my razor page I add the following at the end of the script:

```
<script src="~/js/signalr//dist//browser/signalr.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/HubManager.js"></script>
```

And the `HubManager.js` looks like this:

```
const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("/MainHub", {
        skipNegotiation: true,
        transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets
    })
    .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
    .withAutomaticReconnect()
    .build();

async function start() {
    try {
        await connection.start();
        console.log("connected");
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        setTimeout(() => start(), 5000);
    }
};

connection.onclose(async () => {
    await start();
});

start();
```

I then publish the webapp and navigate to the page that uses SignalR (using Chrome). But when I check the  console, I see that SignalR is polling around every 1s and this error keeps on showing:

> signalr.js:4709 WebSocket connection to 'wss://myurl/MainHub' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

> HubManager.js:61 Error: There was an error with the transport.
> at WebSocket.webSocket.onerror (signalr.js:4728)

- https://myurl/MyWebApp/Home/MyPage
- https://myurl/MyWebApp/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js
- wss://myurl/MainHub

The Websockets protocol is installed on the server. So what can the problem be?

Comment: I'd like to confirm these information with you: 1) Does routing for razor and api part can work on server? 2) If not restrict the client to only use the `WebSockets` transports, does it work? 3) are there any useful info in server logs?

Comment: @FeiHan 1) routing for api work, for razor still unknown as I'm still building the app 2) client is restricted to websockets as shown above 3) iis server logs or signalr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://myurl/MainHub' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

I can reproduce same issue, if I host the ASP.NET Core app as an IIS sub-application "MyWebApp" but not set URL with the sub-app's pathbase on SignalR JavaScript client side.

[image]

To make it work with IIS sub-application, you can try to modify the code as below then republish it to your IIS server.

```
const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("/MyWebApp/MainHub", {
        skipNegotiation: true,
        transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets
    })
    .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
    .withAutomaticReconnect()
    .build();
```

Comment: I get this error now: WebSocket connection to 'wss://myUrl/MyWebApp/MainHub?id=rjBcaMyToBn0GsQ6j2ZXQA' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200

Comment: You can try to configure it with other transports (such as LongPolling) and check if it can work.